# How to destroy complete HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a html page which opens a new page in new window.
so want I to close the first page when second page loades. i don't want to remove any child elements.

i have used this piece of code to remove child

```
var dv;
dv = document.getElementById('parentBody');
dv.parentNode.removeChild(dv);
```

it just removes the child, but i want it to destroy the complete html page.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "destroy".

Comment: You mean `opener.location.replace("otherpage,html")`  ???

Comment: If you mean that you have opened a new browser window and you want to close the original page, it's not possible.

Comment: try this-> document.write(""); at the end or from address bar ?

Comment: @Juhana I think that is what he means.  Agreed it is not possible to close the parent page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correct you want to make a popup or "child window" then have the parent window close.  Unfortunately, I believe this is not possible due to malicious code being executed in the past, therefore it is only possible to close the child from the parent.

By any means, why do you want the child to close the original window?  I believe you could re-size it or change the content via JavaScript and/or AJAX.